# Why does the Bolas Weapon cost 2 if it's a Snare Rank 3 Item?

Tags: weapons, powers, equipment, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm learning to build my own equipment, and I am quite confused on the subject of the Bolas weapon. The price of the weapon is 6 Equipment Points, despite the Snare effect costing 3 points per rank; since the Bolas is listed as a Ranged Snare 3, the cost should be 9 instead.

Why does a bolas cost 6 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question. You're right that the math doesn't work out. I see no update in the 10th anniversary book or in the errata thread. However, the Simple Weapons Gadget Guide lists bolos among a section of "capture weapons" which do not have the cumulative effect on them (so it's just Affliction (Ranged, Extra Condition, Limited Condition)). Perhaps that was their intent. It was not likely a typo from 2E, where the cost was indeed 2 pp/rank, but the default rank for bolos was 4.